# netstat not listing apache IPv4 listen sockets

Tags: apache2, netstat

My apache is listening for *.80 and *.443 connections. And it works fine:

```
 ** root@syslog-ng ** /etc ** Mon Nov 07 13:33:51
# telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!--
    Modified from the Debian original for Ubuntu
    Last updated: 2014-03-19
    See: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1288690
  -->
...
```

Why do the listen sockets only appear as tcp6?

```
 ** root@syslog-ng ** /etc ** Mon Nov 07 14:18:51
# netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     

Ubuntu version: 3.13.0-100-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP
apache version: 2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Same as: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488299/dont-see-apache-running-in-netstat

Comment: If you are not using IPV6 at all, you can disable it on the boot command line, and then `sudo netstat -lnt` will show, for example, this: `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`. On your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line add this `ipv6.disable=1`