# Webpage can not get access from the world!

Tags: apache2, iptables, firewall, webserver, port-forwarding

I have installed a fresh Apache with a fresh Ubuntu server. I did not make any changes to my server yet. The default Apache website is visible from other PCs inside the private network.

The ports 80 and 22 are forwarded properly to the server, and I have setup a fixed IP DHCP 192.168.10.116 from my router.

SSH is accessible from public or private network. But the website is only accessible from the private network. I would like to make the website available to the world.

Note that I have tried this setup with a Windows PC + XAMMP, from which the default Apache webpage had been visible from a public IP.

Below are some details:

```
mg@node1:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

```
mg@node1:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

```
mg@node1:~$ cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

```
mg@node1:~$ sudo netstat -nptl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      702/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      780/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1039/sshd: mg@pts/0
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2340/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      780/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      1039/sshd: mg@pts/0
```

```
mg@node1:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 node1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

```
mg@node1:~$ curl http://192.168.10.116
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML ... ...
```

```
mg@node1:~$ curl http://43.xxx.xxx.95
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 43.xxx.xxx.95 port 80: Connection refused
```

[image: My router port forwarding record]

Comment: You might want to check with your ISP if they block port 80.

Comment: @Terrance The ports are unblocked and from windows10+xammp the website was available through port 80. But I am so confused, why its not working in ubuntu+apache2.

Comment: @Terrance I understood, the port 80 is unblocked, I checked it with my windows+xammp webserver. IF the port 80 is blocked by ISP then it could not happned in windows pc also. Also I pay for this IP monthly and checked with my ISP, they told me all ports are unblocked by them.

Comment: From port 80 missing See https://askubuntu.com/questions/488299/dont-see-apache-running-in-netstat

Comment: @Terrance I have updated my /etc/apache2/ports.conf also, see my netstat plz.

Comment: If they allow you to run `nmap` install it on your system and then scan your external public IP.  You run it as `nmap -PS 43.xxx.xxx.95` and it will return your ports that are being seen.  If you don't see it on your list check your router and make sure that the port it forwarded.  The listen port looks correct there.

Comment: Change `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` to simply `Listen 80` and report back.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you enter that last `curl` command from within your local network? Most routers will not let traffic go "out and back in again".

Comment: @Terrance 
mg@node1:~$ nmap -PS 43.xx.xx2.95
Nmap scan report for 43-x-x-95.exord.net (43.xx.xx.95)
Host is up (0.0066s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
222/tcp  open  rsh-spx
8291/tcp open  unknown



mg@node1:~$ nmap -PS 103.x.x.7
Nmap scan report for 103.x.x.7
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
222/tcp  open  rsh-spx
8291/tcp open  unknown

Comment: @AlexP changed to Liesten 80, and restart apache. but remains same.

Comment: @Jos did ran `curl` inside the network(from the server)

Comment: @Jos, I also get `22/tcp open   ssh 80/tcp closed http` for OPs IP, so not related to the router preventing traffic go "out and back in again".

Comment: @Terrance >> You might want to check with your ISP if they block port 80.
You are right I check with the other port such 8017 its works fine except 80. Contacted with the ISP to unblock it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Terrance I am scared to say that my the port forwarding rules was incorrect with the Mikrotik(except the 8017 port), after correct it the website is visible to the world. Thank you all!