# Can't get apache to serve pages on multi-interface VM

Tags: networking, apache2

I have an ubuntu 18.04 server running on vmware with 2 interfaces, where I installed an apache web server.

I can connect and get the default page via 'curl localhost' and via 'curl ip-addr-of-1st-interface', but 'curl ip-addr-of-2nd-interface' does not work and times out.

Setup is completely at default, no config file changes made whatsoever, just did 'apt-get install apache2' and nothing more. My understanding is that the default config should serve on port 80 on all interfaces.

Firewall is "inactive" via 'ufw status' The apache2 service started successfully, and is "running (active)" as per 'service apache2 status'. netstat shows this listening on :::80 (this was educational...: [Don't see apache running in netstat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488299/dont-see-apache-running-in-netstat)).

I can ping & connect via ssh inbound & outbound on "2nd-interface" (as well as 1st). But I just can't get a port 80 connection on this 2nd interface...

IP config on these two interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# 1st interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 172.26.254.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 172.26.254.0
broadcast 172.26.254.255
gateway 172.26.254.1
dns-search <redacted>
dns-nameservers <redacted>

# 2nd interface
auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
address 172.16.142.201
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 172.16.142.0
broadcast 172.16.142.255
post-up route add -net 172.16.112.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.113.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.122.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.123.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.132.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.133.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.142.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
post-up route add -net 172.16.143.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.142.1
```

Would appreciate any suggestions at this point, been beating my head on this a good part of the day and no closer to a solution. Let me know if additional info would help.

Comment: Check the Apache configuration file and make sure that the `Listen` directive is configured to listen on all interfaces: `Listen 80` , instead of a specific IP only: `Listen 1.2.3.4:80`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The apache config files are all at default, Listen 80 is the default config. Also, as I mentioned, netstat shows the server is listening on port 80 (:::80).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. This is a lab environment, all external access is via web proxy. The 2nd interface's IP was **not** included in the "no_proxy" statements in /etc/environment. WORKING NOW! :)

The way I figured this out was to completely disable the 1st interface. Without being able to reach the proxy at all, curl to the 2nd interface IP printed an error saying as much, making a lightbulb go on in the dim recesses of my brain. While with the first interface up, it just sat there hung up for quite a while, then finally gave me a 'gateway timeout' page, which didn't occur to me to have come from our web proxy.